# Как можно убрать знак - у числа?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть число:
-1000
Как мне в итоге получить: 1000?

Comment: `abs( -1000 )`?

Comment: Или просто умножить на `-1`

Comment: примите ответ если он вам помог — галочка слева от ответа

Comment: `print(1000)` а вообще задача слишком абстрактно сформулирована

Comment: @CrazyElf `получить` => `lambda:1000`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Функция `abs` возвращает абсолютную величину числа. Если ей передать отрицательное число, то она вернёт положительное. Если ей передать положительное число, то она вернёт положительное число.

Answer (score -1):

@ДенисСтепанов solution:

```py
abs(yours)
```

Comment: В случае если попадется положительное число все предложенные операции с -1 дадут противоположенный результат, тоесть добавит знак. Поэтому, думаю стоит ограничиться `abs`

Comment: @Namerek смотря что нужно ...

Comment: Цитирую `Как можно убрать знак - у числа?`

Comment: @Namerek edited...

Answer (score -1):

Можно сделать так:

```
def func(number):
    if number < 0:
        number = number * -1
    elif number >= 0:
        number = number
    return number

my_number = -1000
print(func(my_number))
```

Тогда знак уберется только у числа: )

Comment: `abs` ?????????